# Исправление перевода статьи MCVE

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Когда статья [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) была добавлена, я отправил в чат [список исправлений](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=21113120#21113120), но он был проигнорирован. Копирую сюда, а то статья всё-таки критически важная.

1. Мне не нравится слово "достоверный". Это из какой-то другой области. Воспроизводимый? Верифицируемый?
2. Все короткие тире "–" и дефисы "-", использованные в качестве тире, следует заменить на длинное тире "—".
3. "приведите все элементы" — что такое "элемент"? И с "завершённый" тоже туманно. Может, лучше "самодостаточный" или что-нибудь в этом духе?
4. "пользуйтесь!" — курсивом следует зацепить и восклицательный знак.
5. <s>"не стоит использовать вкладки" — в оригинале речь про tabs vs spaces.</s> "лишь вносят запутанность" — там не запутанность, там про то, что форматирование на СО может разъезжаться, если код отформатирован табами. И редактировать его в браузере одно мучение.
6. "вникнуть в проблему" — воспроизвести.
7. "ошибке, и проблемную" — лишняя запятая.
8. "Просмотрите также весь HTML или XML" — валидация это, а не "просмотр".
9. "отображает проблему" — воспроизводит, опять же.
10. "отображает проблему!" — восклицательный знак тоже следует сделать жирным.
11. "систему, или опробовать" — лишняя запятая.
12. "Краткое не значит усеченное" — по-моему, здесь не про усечение (это второй пункт), а про "сжатие" кода в нечитаемое месиво. Не уверен, какой слово лучше подойдёт, но "усечённое" по смыслу точно не подходит. Сжатое, ужатое, э...
13. "готовы загрузить код по частям и посмотреть" — там про загрузку представленных фрагментов кода, а не про какую-то "загрузку по частям". "загрузить код по частям" можно заменить на "скачать код".
14. "напишите и то, и другое, и третье" — они уже написаны. По смыслу там "предоставьте"/"включите".
15. "Расскажите, каким должен был быть результат" — "был" можно выкинуть, только спотыкаешься о двойное "быть".

Сейчас статью можно понять, только если знаешь английский. Давайте уже наконец исправим это безобразие.

Comment: Правильно. Еще я бы добавил, что в этом [MVCE] так много букв, что вряд ли те, кому он на самом деле нужен, весь его внимательно (и вдумчиво) читают (я, например, так полностью ни разу и не прочел). Нужна какая-то "выжимка" в начале, а уже потом весь (исправленный в соответствии с пунктами 1 -- 15) текст.

Comment: @avp Выжимка — это заголовок, поэтому именно его критично исправить в первую очередь: прочитал "краткий, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый" — и уже понятно, куда двигаться; там же сейчас "краткий, завершённый, достоверный" — поди угадай.

Comment: С заголовком абсолютно точно. Т.е. наверное должно получится что-то в таком духе 1) Заголовок. 2) Развернутое оглавление (выжимка) 3) Текст, обещанный оглавлением

Comment: Отлично, мне очень нравится и само предложение и варианты перевода

Answer (score 2):

[Предложил вариант улучшеной страницы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2780/). Буду рад вашим замечаниям и предложениям.

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить изменения, например, связанные с опечатками и ошибками может, вопрос отмечен как общий.

Comment: Э... Почему текст не запостить ответом?

Comment: @Discord Чтобы можно было затем добавить ссылку на страницу в ответ к вопрос «[Долгосрочные цели для сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981/6)»